# Vuex store unable to update component data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to create a HN clone in 2 panes, but for some reason my vuex store is unable to update the component data.

This is the project link since there are too many files involved.
https://github.com/karansinghgit/hn-vue

This is what it looks like. My aim is to click on one of the articles on the left, and display the hn article with its comments on the right.
So far, I have understood that I need to use vuex to share data but the sharing is not taking place.

It just displays a function signature, when I want it to display the article ID.

[image: This is what it looks like.]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your *store.js* file. You are setting the default state for *currentStory* to [Number](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp). Setting it to an actual number instead should solve your problem:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    currentStory: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    setCurrentStory(state, ID) {
      state.currentStory = ID
    }
  },
  getters: {
    currentStory: state => state.currentStory
  }
})
```

Additionally, in *story.vue*, it is unnecessary to specify *storyID* in the data as you already have it as a computed property (there might be an error thrown for duplicate keys)